# Slick AsyncExecutor Exception

Tags: scala, playframework, threadpool, slick-3.0

I have a **Play 2.5** + **Slick 3.2** application written in Scala 2.11 that uses the **play-slick 2.1.1** plugin.

Configuration of **Play's** thread pool is the default. I know it's the Akka dispatcher. Configuration of **Slick's** thread pool:

```
slick.dbs.data.db.numThreads=75
slick.dbs.data.db.queueSize=1000
```

Configuration of the HikariCP connection pool is the default as well.

There's a Play async action, which retrieves subjects (~8000 subjects in the database) by group id and for each retrieved subject assembles its DTO from two other referenced tables:

```
def getSubjects(groupId: Int) : Future[Seq[SubjectDTO]] = Action.async { request =>
  db.run(retrieveSubjects(request.groupId).withPinnedSession).flatMap { subjects => 
    Future.traverse(subjects)(subjectDTOBuilder())
  }
}

private def subjectDTOBuilder() =
  (subject: Subject) => {
    for {
      subjData <- db.run(getSubjectsAdditionalData(subject.id).withPinnedSession)
      subjInfo <- db.run(getSubjectsMoreInfo(subject.id).withPinnedSession)
    } yield SubjectDTO(subject, subjData, subjInfo)
  }
```

When this Action gets executed it fails at some point with:

```
Task slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@286a41fb rejected from slick.util.AsyncExecutor$$anon$2$$anon$1@46d9be94[Running, pool size = 75, active threads = 75, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 55419]"
```

Exception disappeared when I rewrote `subjectDTOBuilder` to:

```
private def subjectDTOBuilder() =
  (subject: Subject) => {
    val future = db.run(getSubjectsAdditionalData(subject.id).withPinnedSession)
    val future2 = db.run(getSubjectsMoreInfo(subject.id).withPinnedSession)
    for {
      subjData <- future
      subjInfo <- future2
    } yield SubjectDTO(subject, subjData, subjInfo)
  }
```

I know that **now** these "unrelated" futures get executed in parallel, but I don't get the actual reason of **Slick's** exception. What's the issue with **Slick's** thread pool? Can someone explain what can be a possible reason of that exception happening?

Comment: Your re-written signature is significantly different. Where the `getSubjectsAdditionalData` and `getSubjectsMoreInfo` calls get the `subject` from? Could you show us more code so it would be clear? Generally I would expect that version to fail even earlier so I think where the `subject` comes from and how re-written `subjectDTOBuilder` is crucial

Comment: @SergGr, sorry!  posted rewritten function from smartphone. Now fixed it

Comment: Srzhio, are you sure this re-written version consistently works while the other one doesn't? Or maybe it is just a fluke? I would expect both to fail under the same load.

Comment: @SergGr, actually I'm not sure now. Since initial version succeeds occasionally though. But re-written version never failed for many runs.

Answer (score 4):

The error message says "queued tasks = 1000". Default task queue length is also 1000. This means that likely you scheduled too many tasks at once so task executor's input queue is overflown. This queue holds all tasks that are scheduled but still waiting to be executed.

So the solution could be to schedule lesser number of tasks simultaneously or increase queue length. You can configure this behavior by providing own explicit ExecutionContext instance.